# How to schedule a script to run automatically even if Mac is sleeping?

Tags: mac, terminal, python, sleep, launchd

I'm really struggling with this.

Basically I want to run a Python script every 3 hours on my Mac. Even if I'm not using the Mac.
So even if the Mac is asleep I want it to wake up and run the script.

My method of attack is as follows:

1. I've downloaded a third party app called “scenario” that will run scripts when the Mac wakes up.
2. I have put an Apple script in scenario that will call the Python file.
3. The Python file runs the couple of commands I need it to run and then sets a `pmset wake up call` scheduled for 3 hours after the current time.

Now the whole thing is clunky and patched together. To be honest it doesn't really work well because when I wake the laptop myself the code is executed, hence messing up the schedule.

There has to be a better way. Does anyone know where I can look / who could help me on this one?

I have looked `launchd` but I don’t think that will run commands when the laptop is asleep.

My current way makes the laptop wake up and execute code on wake up but how can I counter my problem above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the idea of using `pmset` to schedule a wake-up is a good idea.  I think there are some other tools (Caffeine?) that help with wake-up or sleep schedules, but I'd stic with pmset.

Just put a condition in the AppleScript or Python script to check the last time the script was run (based on a log entry, or a "touched" file), and if it's less than 3 hours since the last run, exit the script.

If you wake the Mac before the 3 hours, you'll need a way to reset the next script-run time.  But, you kind of have to solve that problem already for times when you're using the Mac for more than 3 hours straight.

So, I'd combine Scenario with cron running the same script, maybe once a minute.  Same rules: script checks the last run time, exits if it's too early to run. So now there are 2 ways to trigger your script:

1. Mac has been asleep for 3 hours, pmset wakes it up
2. Mac has been asleep, you wake it before 3 hours
3. Mac is awake, it's been a minute since the last check

In scenario 1, your script runs fully.  in #2, it checks and exits.  In #3, it checks and might exit (too early) or might run fully.

Comment: thanks for the hep on this. that's perfect. I was blind from working on it and couldn't lay it out in my head. that's perfect i will try a cron job. I haven't set up a cron job before, I've done some research and it seems like crontab using terminal is the way to set it up?

Comment: Yes, type `crontab -e` in Terminal to edit it. Try something simple first like writing to a file, so you know it works. And remember cron won’t wake the Mac, so I think you need to combine with your pmset idea so they work together.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I've learned alot here, i appreciate it. It seems like these cron jobs are fairly low impact on the mac as well so i dont think that it will cause much impact on the system if I run it every minute.

Comment: Yes, especially if the cron calls a shell script that just checks for a file/date, and then does the “real” work only if needed.